# Split a string that contains "\"

Tags: c#, split

I'm trying to split a `string` that represents a filepath, so the path contains pictures. For example should the pathstring `#c:\users\common\pictures\2008` be converted to `pictures\2008`. The problem that I encounter is that when I use `\` in a string it gives me an error. Sorry for the dumb question, m new with C#. This is what I've done  so far:

```
string path = "#c:\users\common\pictures\2008";
string[] subs = path.Split('\');

int count = 0;
while(subs[count] != "pictures")
{
      count++;
}

string newPath = "";
for (int i = count; i < subs.Length; i++)
{
      newPath += "\" + subs[i]; 
}

Console.WriteLine(newPath);
```

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow.... "it gives me an error" - don't you think it would be helpful if you _shared that error_ with us? i recommend [taking the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), as well as reading [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [what's on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). but most likely, you just forgot to _escape_ the backslash (by adding another one in front of it)

Comment: You might want to start by using the "verbatim" symbol @ at the front of your string. e.g. string path = @"#c:\users\common\pictures\2008";

Comment: @FranzGleichmann Sorry for that. Whats the syntax for escaping the backlash? is it "\\" like this? If thats the problem then I thank u really much. I'll come around once more at nighttime to see the anwer. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because `\` is a reserved char in C# so you must use it in this way  `'\\'`

In case of string you can add before the special char `@`
In case of char you have to double it `\\`

See the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/verbatim)

```
string path = @"#c:\users\common\pictures\2008";
string[] subs = path.Split('\\');
  
int count = 0;
while (subs[count] != "pictures")
{
   count++;
}

string newPath = "";
for (int i = count; i < subs.Length; i++)
{
   newPath = Path.Combine(newPath ,subs[i]);
}

Console.WriteLine(newPath);
```

Also prefer the use, if possible, of `Path.Combine` since it take care of the escape char for you.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer, that might have solved my problem!

Comment: @name, you are welcome, if this solved your question please accept the answer

Comment: Forgot to do it :) Thanks again

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, C# treats the '\' character as an escape character in a string, so you need to double it up to work.

```
string path = "#c:\\users\\common\\pictures\\2008";
string newPath = path.Substring(path.IndexOf("\\pictures\\") + 1);
```

What this does is take a substring of the 'path' starting at point after where "\pictures\" starts (because you don't want the initial '\').

Or this:

```
string path = "#c:\\users\\common\\pictures\\2008";
string[] subs = path.Split('\\');
int count = Array.IndexOf(subs, "pictures");
string newPath = String.Join("\\", subs, subs.Length - count);
```

Takes the path, splits into an array of the folders, finds the index of the element in the array that is 'pictures' and then joins the array starting at that point.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer!